# Image viewer for Android which can show big images in full resolution

Tags: android, open-source, photography, image-viewer, gallery

So the base question is in the title.

I know one application which can show big images in full resolution — QuickPic `https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.alensw.PicFolder` — but it's nonfree and owned by Cheetah Mobile which has [bad](https://www.change.org/p/google-inc-google-ban-cheetah-mobile-from-google-playstore) [reputation](http://www.androidpolice.com/2015/08/29/popular-photo-gallery-app-quickpic-has-been-bought-by-cheetah-mobile-and-users-are-pissed/).

As a precautionary measure, I'm seeking for alternatives which can also show big images in full resolution and are (ideally) free as in freedom, or at least are well known to not mistreat users.

All else being equal, the less other extra features it has, the better. But if it's open source, I can trim it down myself, of course.

Comment: what is your usecase? do you have a device that can display more than 2000 pixels? What do you mean by "big"? the biggest image the android-os can handle is 4096 X 4096 pixels. if you need more the android app has to do all image processing itself.

Comment: @k3b the use case is to look at images at 1:1 scale (a.k.a. zoom in). screen size is irrelevant here. and big = for example 12MP and higher. all applications I tried obviously do downscale such images.